# How can I extract just the legend from this plot?

Tags: plotting, legending

How can I extract the legend from the following plot?

[image: a line and scatter plot with a legend]

```
fm[name_String, size_ : 8] := 
  ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][name, Offset[size], EdgeForm[]];

ListPlot[
 Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 6}], 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  fm /@ {"Triangle", "Y", "Diamond", "ThreePointedStar", 
    "FivePointedStarSlim", "TripleCross"},
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[52, "ColorList"], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  PointLegend[
   Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 37}, 
   LegendLayout -> (Column[Row /@ #, Spacings -> -1] &)], 
 ImageSize -> 450]
```

This doesn't work. I want to obtain only the legend.

```
PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 37}, 
  LegendLayout -> (Column[Row /@ #, 
      Spacings -> -1] &)] /@ (fm /@ {"Triangle", "Y", "Diamond", 
    "ThreePointedStar", "FivePointedStarSlim", "TripleCross"})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without knowing the exact location of the legend, and after assigning your plot to variable `plot`:

```
First@ Cases[plot, _PointLegend, All]
```

[image: extracted legend]

---

In response to the comment requesting a generator for these legends independent of the plotting function:

```
ClearAll[legend]
Options[legend] = {Joined -> Automatic};
legend[n_Integer?Positive, size : (_?NumericQ) : 8, colorScheme : (_Integer?(1 <= # <= 114 &)) : 52, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 PointLegend[
   ColorData[colorScheme] /@ Range[n],
   Automatic,
   Joined -> OptionValue[Joined],
   LegendMarkers -> (ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][#, Offset[size], EdgeForm[]] & /@ ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][All]),
   LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 37}, 
   LegendLayout -> (Column[Row /@ #, Spacings -> -1] &)
 ]
```

These can be used as follows:

```
{legend[3, 5, 97], 
 legend[5, 8, Joined -> True], 
 legend[4, Joined -> True]}
```

[image: three examples of generated legends]

Comment: Assuming that you don't have that plot, how would you plot the legend? My initial purpose is to plot legend so I can use it for other things as well but this one is also great to know.

Comment: @hana I've added a generator function. See the edit.

Answer (score 6):

```
fm[name_String, size_ : 8] := 
  ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][name, Offset[size], EdgeForm[]];
plot = ListPlot[Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 6}], 
  PlotMarkers -> 
   fm /@ {"Triangle", "Y", "Diamond", "ThreePointedStar", 
     "FivePointedStarSlim", "TripleCross"}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[52, "ColorList"], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 37}, 
    LegendLayout -> (Column[Row /@ #, Spacings -> -1] &)], 
  ImageSize -> 450]
```

```
plot[[2, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, assuming that you don't have that plot, how would you plot the legend?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way may be to set  `ImageSize -> 0`

```
fm[name_String, size_ : 8] := 
  ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][name, Offset[size], EdgeForm[]];
ListPlot[Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 6}], 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  fm /@ {"Triangle", "Y", "Diamond", "ThreePointedStar", 
    "FivePointedStarSlim", "TripleCross"}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[52, "ColorList"], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 37}, 
   LegendLayout -> (Column[Row /@ #, Spacings -> -1] &)], 
 ImageSize -> 0]
```

[image]